# Change the format of the inline monospaced code in confluence to make it stand out

Tags: confluence

How do I change the format of the inline monospaced code in confluence to make it stand out like in *GitHub* markdown where it gets a grey background. In confluence, inline code doesn't seem to stand out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### In Confluence Server

You can go to **Confluence Admin | Look & Feel | Custom HTML | At the END of the HEAD** & add this:

```
<style>
  #com-atlassian-confluence code {
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
</style>
```

Alternatively, you could add this in a custom stylesheet.

#### In Confluence Cloud

This is not possible. Period.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it looks like I can't do anything on the cloud